# Append the result of word count to the end of a file

Tags: shell, wc

I want to count the number of lines in `example.txt` and append the result to the end of this file. How can I do this?

I tried:

```
wc -l > example.txt
```

Comment: You notice that each time you'll do it, number of line increase ?

Answer (score 3):

```
wc -l example.txt >> example.txt
```

Comment: This will include file name, not the number of lines only.

Answer (score 2):

As you know, wc -l by default, includes the result number plus the file name. If for some reason it is better to have literally just the result number only, try this:

```
wc -l example.txt | cut -d' ' -f1 >> example.txt
```

So if example.txt started with only 3 lines, eg:

```
a
b
c
```

After you run the above, use `tail` to look at the last lines (in this case very few lines so it views the entire file) you see:

```
$ tail example.txt
a
b
c
3
```

### Explanation

- you already know `wc -l example.txt` which gives default result line count and file name, eg `3 example.txt`
- the `cut` command helps extract "fields" from lines
- the `-d` is to set delimiter/field separator, which we specify is `' '` , a space.
- the `-f1` means choose the first field, so given `wc` output was `3 example.txt` the `3` is the first field
- `>>` appends, so it saves the result `3`, to end of the file `example.txt`

Answer (score 0):

The following script adds the line count to the end of the file if it is not already there, but deletes and replaces it if there is already a line count.

This allows you to run this script every time your file(s) are
edited without adding multiple 'Line count:' lines.

```
#! /bin/bash

count=$(wc -l "$1" | cut -d' ' -f1)

tail -1 "$1" | grep -q '^Line count: '
if [ $? ]; then
    count=$(( $count - 1 )) # don't count the 'Line count' line
    sed -i -e '$ d' "$1"
    echo "Line count: $count" >> "$1"
else
    echo "Line count: $count" >> "$1"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

To append **only** the amount of lines, you can try this

```
$ cat example.txt | wc -l >> example.txt
```

This will only display the total amount of lines in the file